# Set request's header on Authorize Attribute of the Controller in Asp.net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

I want to set the header request before checking the auhorization, but i'm looking for the event to execute the modification.
**This my Implementation of IAuthorizationFilter :**

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {  

        public MyAuthorizationFilter()
        {
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

**This is my code in Startup :**

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter));
            });
```

**This is my call of MyAuthorizationFilter in the controller :**

```
 [MyAuthorizationFilter()]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
    }
```

Comment: ClaimRequirementFilter -> do you want to add a global auth requirement?

Comment: _set the header request before checking the auhorization_? How do you mean?

Comment: @abdusco No, I don't want to add a global auth requierement. I mean when a request is recieved to the controller, the authorize attribute will check the validity of the the JWT bearer token. i want to set the request's header before authorize attribute start checking the validty

Comment: You don't need filters to validate JWT. You need to add a JWT auth scheme `services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer()` then enable auth middleware `app.UseAuthentication().UseAuthorization()` which will validate the token for you

Comment: @abdusco Yes i've already added this, but i want to edit the request before my app start checking jwt token validation.

Comment: Then add a Middleware before `.UseAuthentication()` then modify the request directly before calling the next middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the request, add a middleware before the auth middleware:

```cs
app.UseRouting();

// add a middleware before auth
app.Use(
    async (context, next) => {
        // modify the request
        context.Request.Headers["A"] = "1";
        // call the next middleware
        await next();
    }
);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(...);
```